# Does Blink work in the outer planes?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, planes

Does [Blink](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Blink#content) work in the outer planes? The spell it states:

> you vanish from your current plane of existence and appear in the Ethereal Plane

as well as:

> While on the Ethereal Plane, you can see and hear the plane you originated from, which is cast in shades of gray, and you can't see anything there more than 60 feet away

This seems to be written in particular contrast to the Etherealness spell (see also [*Can you become Ethereal in the Outer Planes?*](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/109181/can-you-become-ethereal-in-the-outer-planes/109191)), which says:

> This spell has no effect if you cast it while you are on the Ethereal Plane or a plane that doesn't border it, such as one of the Outer Planes.

This seems to imply that Blink will work fine on the Outer Planes, but does it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### It will work fine on the outer planes

The limitation on the *Etherealness* spell is just that; a limitation on the  *Etherealness* spell. *Blink* has no such limitation.

However, your DM has to decide if you can see the outer plane you left.

From *Blink*:

> While on the Ethereal Plane, you can see and hear the plane you originated from ...

From the DMG (p.48):

> From the Border Ethereal, a traveler can see into whatever plane it overlaps ...

My ruling would be that the *general rule* is that an outer plane doesn't overlap the Ethereal but the *specific* rule of *Blink* allows you to see it notwithstanding; because magic.

Comment: So what happens if you cast Blink while you are on the Ethereal Plane?

Comment: @enkryptor: “[…] (the spell fails and the casting is wasted if you were already on that plane).”